# How can I get html completion in JSP files in Atom?

Tags: html, autocomplete, atom-editor

In atom html is autocompleted (markups, properties, etc...) when editing `.html` files. Is there a way I can get the same when editing `.jsp` files ?

NB: https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-jsp doesn't fit as it only does autocompletion for jsp-specific code, not for standard html.